# Swift impact of performance when splitting project up into frameworks

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, compiler-optimization

Are there any drawbacks of splitting up a Swift project into several frameworks? In my current application I don't *need* to do this but it would logically separate the different parts of my code so I intended to put the code into multiple frameworks (embedded binaries). However, I don't know if Swift's apparently awesome feature 'Whole Module Optimization' is affected by creating several modules.

Furthermore, are there any other drawbacks of using frameworks or performance upsides?

Thanks for your clarifications ;)

Comment: Probably only the size of the executable grows a bit.

Comment: There really is no straightforward, one-size-fits-all answer to this question. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi I'm trying to accomplish logic separation of data however I'm concerned that Swift's powerful optimization tool 'Whole Module Optimization' wouldn't be able to perform that well

Answer (score 0):

One thing I know is that with framework, you can reduce compiling time. Because you can compile your stable framework and reuse it. Then xcode only compile your main project.

The drawback (in my opinion) is that you have to `import framework` whenever you use it.

Comment: That'd mean that Whole Module Optimization wouldn't be useful, wouldn't it?

Comment: @OliverBorchert I haven't used it enough to say. But I have to turn it off because Whole Module Optimization have a tons of bugs with my project. i.e Selector / ...